# Comparing subarrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm wondering what would be the best way to obtain a boolean array as a result of comparison of inner "subarrays" and an array with a smaller number of dimensions. For example, given:

```
a = array([[[[-1, -1], [-1,  1]],
            [[-1, -1], [ 1,  1]]],
           [[[ 0, -1], [ 1,  1]],
            [[ 0,  1], [-1, -1]]]])
a.shape == (n, m, k, l)
```

and

```
b = [-1, -1]
b.shape == (l,)
```

I would like to get:

```
c = array([[[True, False],
            [True, False]],
           [[False, False],
            [False, True]]])
c.shape == (n, m, k)
```

However, in general we could imagine:

```
b.shape == (k, l)
c.shape == (n, m)
```

Comment: What is `a.shape`?

Comment: Added that info to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
logical_and.reduce(a == b, axis = -1)
```

as the shape of `b` matches the last dimension of `a` it will be automatically broadcast so you can directly apply the `==` operator which will compare pointwise returning a logical array of the same shape as `a`. The reduce operation the returns True for all "rows" that contain only True values (reducing `ndim` by one)

Second example (be sure to notice the difference in the `axis` parameter):

```
>>> b = [[-1,-1],[-1,1]]                                                                                                             
>>> logical_and.reduce(a == b, axis = (-2,-1))
array([[ True, False],                                                                                                                                      
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: More generally, `axis=tuple(range(-b.ndim, 0))`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that the reduction methods supported multiple axes. When did that become available?

Comment: @MadPhysicist To be honest I don't store these subtleties, it's more trial-and-error; but I only recently stumbled over the concept of tuple axis args; so yes they may be a relatively new addition.

Answer (score 3):

Since the last dimensions of `a` and `b` match, the expression `a == b` will broadcast correctly to a boolean array the size of `a`.

Since you want to know if all the elements of a subarray match, you can reduce the last dimension with `np.all(a == b, axis=-1)`.

For the case where `b` is multidimensional, you will have to ravel the last dimensions into one, because `np.all` does not yet accept a proper sequence of dimensions. Something like `shp = a.shape[:-b.ndim] + (b.size,); np.all((a == b).reshape(shp), axis=-1)` should work in the general case.

**Update**

Apparently `np.all` has supported a tuple of axes as the `axis` argument for some time now. Then the general case simplifies significantly to `np.all(a == b, axis=tuple(range(-b.ndim, 0)))`. This will work for the 1D case just fine too.